# Firefox shows random characters instead of fallback image when Shockwave Flash is disabled

Tags: html, flash, firefox, fallback, shockwave

I have the following code to display the swf object on the page. It works well in all browsers. However, if shockwave flash turned off in Firefox, it won't fallback into image and show bunch of characters instead looking like "CWS q�x��wX�Y�7z�..." All other browsers fallback to the image. I verified that we serve application/x-shockwave-flash MIME type on our server.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
swfobject.registerObject("fd_flash","8.0.0");
</script>
<div>
<object height="376" id="fd_flash" width="940">
<param name="movie" value="path/file.swf" />
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<object data="path/file.swf" height="376" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="940">
<!--<![endif]-->
<div><img src="path/image.jpg" /></div>
<!--[if !IE]>-->
</object>
<!--<![endif]-->
</object>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you link to the page in question?  It really sounds like a MIME type issue, even if you said you checked it already....

Comment: It is a main page banner on www.jiwire.com

Comment: That would be http://www.jiwire.com/sites/default/files/JiWire-FD-Jan2012-a.swf which the site sends as text/plain as far as I can tell.  Certainly when I get that url with wget the HTTP headers include `Content-Type: text/plain`.

Comment: Hmm, yes you are right. However, I downloaded this swf file from our staging server and it also has text/plain header, however Firefox gracefully fallback into image there.

Comment: Hard to say what you staging server is doing without having access to it...

Answer (score 0):

You could try another way of using `swfobject`. Add a link in your `<head>` to your swfobject.js file, then in your `<body>` put this:

```
<div id="yourFlashDiv">
    <!-- ALTERNATE CONTENT GOES HERE -->
    <p>This paragraph will show if your Flash content won't</p>

    <!-- FLASH CONTENT GOES HERE -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // <![CDATA[
      var so = new SWFObject("path/file.swf", "SwfTitleGoesHere", "376", "940", "8", "#FFFFFF");
      so.addParam("wmode", "opaque");
      so.write("yourFlashDiv");
      // ]]>
    </script>
</div>
```

This is what I've used for swf display, and it has failed gracefully on every browser I've tested. Hope this helps

Comment: I couldn't get it to work in drupal. I paste this code in the content area and after I save it shows me many warnings and only displays the alternate content.

Comment: What kind of warnings? Have you made sure that both jquery and swfobject.js are loaded in your HTML <head>?

Comment: Both libraries are loaded.                                     Warning: DOMDocumentFragment::appendXML() [domdocumentfragment.appendxml]: Entity: line 10: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name in filter_dom_serialize_escape_cdata_element() (line 1111 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/6.0 (branch)/modules/filter/filter.module).
Warning: DOMDocumentFragment::appendXML() [domdocumentfragment.appendxml]: //--><!]]> in filter_dom_serialize_escape_cdata_element() (line 1111 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/6.0 (branch)/modules/filter/filter.module).